# Problem with soft keyboard which hides some fields

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, keyboard

I have problem when a keyboard open and hides a edittext and button and there is no scroll.
I searched the internet and found some solution like adding to AndroidManifest.xml `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`, `ScrollView` on top (of Login_Activity.xml),or even `fillViewport="true"` but none of them works for me.

I have `TabLayout`on my activity and in TabLayout I have Login_Fragment.xml and the editText fields are in it.
Here's my code:

Manifest:

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.ideomobile.common.ui.custom.WebViewActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Login_Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@color/BackgroundColor"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_Info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/info_button"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/logo" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:background="@color/BackgroundColor"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textColor="@color/finger_print_blue"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_indicator_color"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/popups_blue_background"
    app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6.5"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:background="@color/login_button_disable"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/login_button"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/BackgroundColor"
        android:textSize="11pt"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Login_Fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/BackgroundColor"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textDirection="rtl">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lines_for_finger_print"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finger_print_firat_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/add_fingerprint_title_line_1"
        android:textColor="@color/finger_print_blue"
        android:textSize="11pt"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finger_print_second_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/add_finger_print_title_line_2"
        android:textColor="@color/text_login_fields"
        android:textSize="8pt" />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:digits="@string/fingerprint_digits_allows"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/user_name"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@color/text_login_fields"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text_login_fields"
    android:textSize="11pt"
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
    android:digits="@string/fingerprint_digits_allows"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/user_password"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text_login_fields"
    android:textSize="11pt"
    android:singleLine="true"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewforgotPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="@string/link_forgot_password"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/finger_print_blue"
    android:textSize="7pt" />
```

Need to mention that no need to scroll when there is no keyboard. Only when the keyboard opens need to be able to scroll.

Can you help me solve it?

Comment: If any answer helps you then you are supposed to mark that as "accepted" and upvote so that it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **windowSoftInputMode**

```
  <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activity.LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Tried it  again but it doesn't work (the same as before)

Comment: It is still working fine in my application. Try **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** inside particular activity tag

Comment: Probably something in my layouts avoids it to scroll, but what is it...

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content". Try changing it to match_parent